# Alternative Names for Eastertide?

Tags: easter, liturgical-calendar

So I just asked the question why Pentecost is called Pentecost before Pentecost in the Eastern Church. And it got me thinking, what are alternative names for Eastertide?

I am aware of Eastertide, Easter Time and Season, Paschaltide, Paschal Time and Season

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative Names for Eastertide?**

> [**Eastertide**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastertide) (also called the **Easter Season** as well as **Easter Time**) or **Paschaltide** (also called the **Paschal Season** as well as **Paschal Time**) is a festal season in the liturgical year of Christianity that focuses on celebrating the Resurrection of Jesus Christ.

The Eastern Orthodox Church calls Eastertide: [**Pentecost**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentecost).

The Catholic Maronite Church uses the term [Season of Resurrection](http://www.maronitemusic.org/liturgical-year/resurrection) for Eastertide.

> [Eastertide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastertide) is the period of 50 days, spanning from Easter Sunday to Pentecost Sunday

Occasionally one see the Roman Rite employing this term for Eastertide also.

> Perhaps nothing captures the spirit of Easter more than the “Exultet,” the great Easter Proclamation composed about the fifth century and sung on Holy Saturday night in Catholic churches across 15 centuries.
>
> The Exultet, an ecstatic hymn of praise of the risen Christ, begins with these powerful words: “Exult, let them exult, the hosts of heaven, exult, let angel ministers of God exult, let the trumpet of heaven sound aloud our mighty King’s triumph! Be glad, let earth, as glory floods her, ablaze with light from her eternal King, let all corners of the earth be glad, knowing an end to gloom and darkness.”
>
> The stirring words of this proclamation spill over into the liturgy of the Easter season as we call to mind and celebrate the resurrection of Christ from the dead. But Easter is not simply poetry, it is one of the greatest events of history (along with the creation of the world and the Incarnation). - [The Easter Proclamation and the ***Resurrection Season***](http://www.icatholic.org/article/the-easter-proclamation-and-the-resurrection-season-85412498)

To a lesser degree Easter is expressed by some as the Season of Hope:

> [Easter is a Season of Hope](https://cclse.org/easter-is-a-season-of-hope/)